# EasyMock: Method with a callback argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have a situation like this:

```
class A {
  void methodA(Callback cb) {
    ...
    cb.onResult(result);
  }
}

class B {
  void methodB(A a) {
    a.methodA(new Callback() {
      void onResult(Result r) {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and the question is: How can I test the "B.methodB" with different "result" with EasyMock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `capture` the `Callback` that is passed to `methodA`

```
Capture<Callback> cap = new Capture<Callback>();
mockA.methodA(capture(cap));
replay(mockA);
instanceOfB.methodB(mockA);
Callback cb = cap.getValue();

// now we can call cb.onResult with a mocked Result instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you refactor to make it easier to test?

```
class B {
  void methodB(A a) {
    a.methodA(new Callback() {
      void onResult(Result r) {
        onResultFromA(r);
      }
    });
  }
  void onResultFromA(Result r) {
  }
}
```

Then just test `onResultFromA()`?

You don't really care where `r` comes from, just that you do the right thing with it?

Or do you?

Comment: Yes I can but I want to know if it's possible to do it with EasyMock.

Comment: I don't think so. I'd probably make the code more testable first and only resort to complex mocks (maybe using PowerMock or byte-code manipulators like javassist and CGLIB) if you're dealing with code you can't change.